# SQL left join for inactive records

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables. One of them has actual names and the other one has nicknames used by those people.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [active] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerAKA](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [akaFirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [akaLastName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([id], [firstName], [lastName], [active]) VALUES (1, N'Op', N'Test', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([id], [firstName], [lastName], [active]) VALUES (2, N'M', N'J', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([id], [firstName], [lastName], [active]) VALUES (3, N'John', N'Doe', 1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customer] OFF

INSERT [dbo].[CustomerAKA] ([id], [akaFirstName], [akaLastName]) VALUES (1, N'Hello', N'Test')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerAKA] ([id], [akaFirstName], [akaLastName]) VALUES (1, N'Mahalo', N'Test')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerAKA] ([id], [akaFirstName], [akaLastName]) VALUES (3, N'Jonny', N'Doe')
```

My query is :

```
select *
from dbo.Customer c1 
left join dbo.CustomerAKA c2 on c2.id = c1.id
where not exists ( select *
                   from dbo.Customer c
                   where c.id = c1.id
                   and c.active = 0 )
```

Even though Op Test is not active, I still want to get the nicknames for him:

```
1   Hello   Test
1   Mahalo  Test
```

So my output should be :

```
M   J
John    Doe
Jonny   Doe
Hello   Test
Mahalo  Test
```

Any ideas?

Comment: modify the subquery to have an `or` which includes the ID of your test user (1) `where c.id = c1.id
                   and (c.active = 0 OR c.ID = 1)`

Comment: Are you sure this is DB2? Looks like SQLServer (the tag you chose)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you want
But seems something like

```
select *
from dbo.Customer c1
left join dbo.CustomerAKA c2 on c2.id = c1.id
where  c1.active = 1 or (c1.firstname = "Op" and c1.lastname = "Test")
Order by c1.active desc
```

Or like

```
select 
coalesce(c2.firstname, c1.firstname) as firstname,
coalesce(c2.lastname, c1.lastname) as lastname
from dbo.Customer c1
Left outer join dbo.CustomerAKA c2 on c2.id = c1.id
Order by c1.active desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using an id for a specific row is unlikely to work against real tables for this sort of data.  For one thing, presumably OP doesn't actually know the list of all ids that should be used there.

Comment: Why u want to show hello and mahallo tests? U want all active and inactive?? It is confusing to me.. u may filter by name to fit 100% to your question. Will edit my answer

Comment: If you can explain the rule to show or not the innactives  would help. U Just said that want Op tests to be shown too

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname
from customer c
union all
select ca.akafirstname, c.akalastname
from customeraka ca join
     customer c
     on ca.id = c.id
where c.active = 1;
```

Comment: ... Given the sample output data, I think you have that `where` clause on the wrong side (and the condition should be flipped).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH 
  Customer (id, firstName, lastName, active) AS
(
VALUES 
  (1, 'Op', 'Test', 0)
, (2, 'M', 'J', 1)
, (3, 'John', 'Doe', 1)
) 
, CustomerAKA (id, akaFirstName, akaLastName) AS
(
VALUES 
  (1, 'Hello', 'Test')
, (1, 'Mahalo', 'Test')
, (3, 'Jonny', 'Doe')
) 
*/
SELECT firstName, lastName
FROM Customer 
WHERE active = 1
  UNION ALL
SELECT c2.akaFirstName AS firstName, c2.akaLastName AS lastName
FROM CustomerAKA c2
JOIN Customer c1 ON c1.id=c2.id;
```